# Am I not able to break a While loop inside of a function?

Tags: python, function, while-loop

> So how come it doesn't allow me to break the while loop in the function?
> also, I didn't want to use a mainloop because I didn't understand how it worked. if you cant figure out whats going on, maybe you could reformat the code with a working mainloop? any help is greatly appreciated! ______________________________________________________________________

```
#imports
import turtle
import math
import random
import time
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

#variables
BossSpawnx = 0
BossSpawny = 0
PlayerSpawnx = -250
PlayerSpawny = -250
BossMovement = 0
global BossMovement


#initiation
Screen().screensize(500, 500)
Screen().title("Tiny Turtles")
Screen().bgcolor("gray")
print("welcome to Tiny Turtles")

#Initiating Boss
Boss = Turtle("turtle")
Boss.color("red")
turtle.delay(None)
Boss.penup()
Boss.goto(BossSpawnx, BossSpawny)
Boss.color("red")

#Initiating Player
Player = Turtle("turtle")
Player.color("cyan")
Player.penup()
Player.goto(PlayerSpawnx, PlayerSpawny)

while True:
    #Functions
    def k1():
        Player.forward(25)

    def k2():
        Player.left(35)

    def k3():
        Player.right(35)

    def k4():
        Player.backward(25)


    def follow_runner():
        print("Following")
        if BossMovement == 4:
            Boss.setheading(Boss.towards(Player))
            Boss.forward(min(Boss.distance(Player), 8))
            if Boss.xcor() == Player.xcor() and Boss.ycor() == Player.ycor():
                print('Turtletastrophy!')
                break
            else:
                Screen().ontimer(follow_runner, 10)
        else:
            BossMovement += 1



        Screen().onkey(k1, "Up")  # the up arrow key

        Screen().onkey(k2, "Left")  # the left arrow key

        Screen().onkey(k3, "Right")  # you get it!

        Screen().onkey(k4, "Down")


        Screen().listen()

        follow_runner()
```

Comment: You should not be defining functions within a while loop. You can have while loops inside of functions but your code is telling the computer to define the function over and over again (if that is even valid?). Functions should not be defined inside while loops.

Comment: Why are you trying to change scope of global variable while in global scope? It is a syntax error! I shared a working example as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well. First, move function definition outside the loop. Why are you defining inside a loop?

Also, when I try to run this code get below syntax error:

`SyntaxError: name 'BossMovement' is assigned to before global declaration`

Therefore move `global` keyword inside relative function. Why are you changing scope of global variable inside global scope?

Also you should do key assignment for single time.

Here is a working example:

```
# imports
import turtle
import math
import random
import time
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

# variables
BossSpawnx = 0
BossSpawny = 0
PlayerSpawnx = -250
PlayerSpawny = -250
BossMovement = 0

# initiation
Screen().screensize(500, 500)
Screen().title("Tiny Turtles")
Screen().bgcolor("gray")
print("welcome to Tiny Turtles")

# Initiating Boss
Boss = Turtle("turtle")
Boss.color("red")
turtle.delay(None)
Boss.penup()
Boss.goto(BossSpawnx, BossSpawny)
Boss.color("red")

# Initiating Player
Player = Turtle("turtle")
Player.color("cyan")
Player.penup()
Player.goto(PlayerSpawnx, PlayerSpawny)


def k1():
    Player.forward(25)


def k2():
    Player.left(35)


def k3():
    Player.right(35)


def k4():
    Player.backward(25)


def follow_runner():
    global BossMovement
    print("Following")
    if BossMovement == 4:
        Boss.setheading(Boss.towards(Player))
        Boss.forward(min(Boss.distance(Player), 8))
        if Boss.xcor() == Player.xcor() and Boss.ycor() == Player.ycor():
            print('Turtletastrophy!')
            return True
        else:
            Screen().ontimer(follow_runner, 10)
            return False
    else:
        BossMovement += 1
        return False


Screen().onkey(k1, "Up")  # the up arrow key

Screen().onkey(k2, "Left")  # the left arrow key

Screen().onkey(k3, "Right")  # you get it!

Screen().onkey(k4, "Down")
Screen().listen()

done = False
while not done:
    done = follow_runner()
```

Comment: If it worked, accept - vote up answer instead of commented. So others can benefit.